# How to pass array values from form to JavaScript to AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to pass array form to JavaScript and then to AJAX. here is form:

```html
<form>
 <?php
        $c=$_POST['sweater'];
  foreach ($c as $sid){
   echo $sid;
   $query1="select * from `usersweater` where `Sweaterid`='$sid'";
   $result1=mysql_query($query1);
   $row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
   $sweaternikname=$row1['SNickname'];
   $sweaterpic=$row1['Sweaterpic'];
   echo $sweaterpic;
 ?>

 <div style=" ">
  <ul class="sweaters">
   <li> <h4><?php echo $sweaternikname; ?></h4> <img src="upload/<?php echo $sweaterpic; ?>"> </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 

     <!-------requester's own sweater details--------------->
 <input type="hidden" name="sid[]" value="<?php echo $sid;?>">
 <?php } ?>
        <div style="float:right; margin-right:10px;">
  <input type="submit" name="next" onclick="ajaxFunction()" value="NEXT" class="btn woo_btn btn-primary">
  <input type="button" name="cancel" value="CANCEL" class="btn woo_btn btn-primary">
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is script :

```html
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function ajaxFunction(){
 var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
 try{
  ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } catch (e){

  try{
   ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (e) {
   try{
    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   } catch (e){

    alert("Your browser broke!");
    return false;
   }
  }
 }
 ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
   var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
   ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
  }
 }
var elements = document.getElementsByName('sid[]');  
}
ajaxRequest.open("POST","Usercloset2.php" ,true);
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
ajaxRequest.send(elements);
}
</script>
```

How to send sid[] in form of array so that I can use this array as used in above page?

Comment: Remove [] use this var elements = document.getElementsByName('sid');

Comment: How are you getting on with this? Don't forget to use your network monitor inside your browser to view the request and response of your AJAX op.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a query string and send it like

```
function ajaxFunction() {
    var ajaxRequest; // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
    try {
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {

        try {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {

                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    var elements = document.getElementsByName('sid[]');
    var params = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        params.push(elements[i].name + '=' + encodeURIComponent(elements[i].value))
    }

    ajaxRequest.open("POST", "Usercloset2.php?" + params.join('&'), true);
    ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajaxRequest.send();
}
```

Comment: how to take other side??    i think  $_POST['params']; ??

Answer (score -1):

First you have to declare the variable as array type as shown below

`var elements=[];`

then get the value from the input feild using below code

`elements=document.getElementsByName('sid');`

and then pass it in you url.

hope this will sove your problem

Comment: `var elements=[];` assigns an array to the variable. It doesn't make the variable "array type". `elements=document.getElementsByName('sid');` overwrites the array with a NodeList, making the original array assignment pointless. *and then pass it in you url* —that stringifies to `"[object NodeList]"` which isn't very useful.